# Is manually partitioning as one table per document evil?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I wish to use postgresql to store 10k+ independent "documents" each with 10k+ rows and growing. They have the same schema. For active documents I am expecting:

1. frequent inserts and updates
2. regular fetch of a complete document
3. rare deletion
4. no querying across documents (assume full-text search is handled elsewhere).

The standard way would be to create a single table with a doc_id but I assume so many rows would be a performance nightmare i.e. both #1 and #2 will slow down with size of the table yet I'm not getting any benefit out of it being a single table.

I believe I would get better performance and admin flexibility (e.g. perform piecemeal schema upgrades, perform pg_reorg, future sharding etc.) by creating one table per document. I can't see any benefit from using a master table and setting up triggers.

Is this acceptable, a terrible anti-pattern or is there another way I should be tackling this?